# Javascript function just won't run

Tags: javascript, html, function

This script just won't work and I cant find out why. It's supposed to set a "p" element depending on the outcome but it just won't work. I've included the script below. I'm only just starting to learn JavaScript so it's probably a stupid error.

```js
var spearman = 12;
var swordsman = 10;
var berserker = 68;
var archer = 16;
var crossbowman = 13;
var nordicArcher = 56;
var armouredHorseman = 22;
var lancerHorseman = 20;
var axeRider = 82;
var handCart = 500;
var oxCart = 2500;
var spearmanCap;
var swordsmanCap;
var berserkerCap;
var archerCap;
var crossbowmanCap;
var nordicArcherCap;
var armouredHorsemanCap;
var lancerHorsemanCap;
var axeRiderCap;
var handCartCap;
var oxCartCap;
var numberOfCastles;
var numberOfForts;
var silverRequired;
var troopsCanCarry;

function enoughSilver() {
    spearmanCap = spearman * document.getElementById("spearmanNum").value;
    swordsmanCap = swordsman * document.getElementById("swordsmanNum").value;
    berserkerCap = berserker * document.getElementById("berserkerNum").value;
    archerCap = archer * document.getElementById("archerNum").value;
    crossbowmanCap = crossbowman * document.getElementById("crossbowmanNum").value;
    nordicArcherCap = nordicArcher * document.getElementById("nordicArcherNum").value;
    armouredHorsemanCap = armouredHorseman * document.getElementById("armouredHorsemanNum").value;
    lancerHorsemanCap = lancerHorseman * document.getElementById("lancerHorsemanNum").value;
    axeRiderCap = axeRider * document.getElementById("axeRiderNum").value;
    handCartCap = handCart * document.getElementById("handCartNum").value;
    oxCartCap = oxCart * document.getElementById("oxCartNum").value;
    
    troopsCanCarry = spearmanCap + swordsmanCap + berserkerCap + archerCap + crossbowmanCap + nordicArcherCap + armouredHorsemanCap + lancerHorsemanCap + axeRiderCap + handCartCap + oxCartCap;
    
    numberOfCastles = document.getElementById("attackerCastlesNum");
    numberOfForts = document.getElementById("attackerFortNum");
       
    if (document.getElementById("landRefYes").checked) {
        if (document.getElementById("yourcastle").checked) {     
            numberOfForts = numberOfForts * 5;
            numberOfCastles = numberOfCastles + numberOfForts;
            silverRequired = 1000 * numberOfCastles;
            silverRequired = silverRequired / 2;
            if (troopsCanCarry == silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops can carry exacly the right amount of silver. This is almost certainly a real attack";
            }
            else if (troopsCanCarry > silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops can carry more than enough silver to capture your castle. Keep your troops inside your castle and consider calling support!";
            }
            else if (troopsCanCarry < silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops cant carry enough silver this isnt a real attack";
            }
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("yourfort").checked) {
            numberOfForts = numberOfForts * 5;
            numberOfCastles = numberOfCastles + numberOfForts;
            numberOfCastles = numberOfCastles * 5;
            silverRequired = 1000 * numberOfCastles;
            if (troopsCanCarry == silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops can carry exacly the right amount of silver. This is almost certainly a real attack";
            }
            else if (troopsCanCarry > silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops can carry more than enough silver to capture your castle. Keep your troops inside your castle and consider calling support!";
            }
            else if (troopsCanCarry < silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops cant carry enough silver this isnt a real attack";
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error")
        }
        
        
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("landRefNo").checked) {
        if (document.getElementById("yourcastle").checked) {     
            numberOfForts = numberOfForts * 5;
            numberOfCastles = numberOfCastles + numberOfForts;
            silverRequired = 1000 * numberOfCastles;
            if (troopsCanCarry == silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops can carry exacly the right amount of silver. This is almost certainly a real attack";
            }
            else if (troopsCanCarry > silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops can carry more than enough silver to capture your castle. Keep your troops inside your castle and consider calling support!";
            }
            else if (troopsCanCarry < silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops cant carry enough silver this isnt a real attack";
            }
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("yourfort").checked) {
            numberOfForts = numberOfForts * 5;
            numberOfCastles = numberOfCastles + numberOfForts;
            numberOfCastles = numberOfCastles * 5;
            silverRequired = 1000 * numberOfCastles;
            if (troopsCanCarry == silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops can carry exacly the right amount of silver. This is almost certainly a real attack";
            }
            else if (troopsCanCarry > silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops can carry more than enough silver to capture your castle. Keep your troops inside your castle and consider calling support!";
            }
            else if (troopsCanCarry < silverRequired) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The troops cant carry enough silver this isnt a real attack";
            }
        }
    else {
        console.log("Error");
    }
        
        
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Could it be a sliver attack?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="isItSilver.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Could it be a sliver attack?</h1>
    <p>You can use this tool to calculate wether the attacking troops can carry enough silver to capture your castle. <br>If they dont then you can safely remove your troops let them take your resources and leave.</p>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your castle under attack is a:</legend>
        <p>
            <input id="yourcastle" type="radio" name="underattack" checked="checked"><label for="yourcastle">Castle</label>
            <input id="yourfort" type="radio" name="underattack"><label for="yourfort">Fortress</label>
    
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Attacker Information</legend>
        <p>(if multiple players are attacking use the lowest players information)</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" value="1" id="attackerCastlesNum"><label for="attackerCastlesNum">How many Castles does the attacker have?</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" value="0" id="attackerFortNum"><label for="attackerFortNum">How many Fortresses does the attacker have?</label>
                </td>
        
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Is land reform on?</legend>
        <p>
            <input id="landRefYes" type="radio" name="landRef"><label for="landRefYes">Yes, land reform is on</label>
            <input id="landRefNo" type="radio" name="landRef" checked="checked"><label for="landRefNo">No, land reform is not on</label>
            <br>
            Land reform means Castles & Fortresses cost 50% silver
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>How many troops are attacking?</legend>
        <p>Use the amount of troops that arrived before the first round. If any support has arrived add those troops to the troops that arrived before round one
        </p>
        <tabel>
            <tr>
                <td>Spearmen:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="spearmanNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Swordsman:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="swordsmanNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Berserker:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="berserkerNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Archer:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="archerNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Crossbowman:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="crossbowmanNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Nordic Archer:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="nordicArcherNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Armoured Horseman:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="armouredHorsemanNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Lancer Horseman:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="lancerHorsemanNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Axe Rider:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="axeRiderNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Hand Cart:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="handCartNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Ox Cart:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="oxCartNum">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tabel> 
    </fieldset>
    <button id="isItASilverAttack" onclick="enoughSilver()">Is It A Silver Attack?</button>
    <p id="answer"></p>
    <p>If the troops cant hold enough silver to capture your castle then you can move your troops out and let the attacker steal some of your resources. <span id="warning">Warning!</span> If reinforcments arrive then you must do this again </p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `numberOfCastles = document.getElementById("attackerCastlesNum"); numberOfForts = document.getElementById("attackerFortNum");` are assigning `HTMLInputElement`s, not numbers. Use `.value`. Use `Number(`…`)` additionally to not confuse types.

Comment: There is almost certainly much more javascript in the question than is necessary to reproduce the issue you are facing. Please rewrite your question to be a minimal, complete, and verifiable example as detailed in this document. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve If you do this, you'll get much better answers and your question will be much better received.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to get the values there :

```
numberOfCastles = document.getElementById("attackerCastlesNum").value;
numberOfForts = document.getElementById("attackerFortNum").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few minor syntax errors in your code (though these are not the cause of your issue):

(1) You have misspelled the HTML tag "table" as "tabel"; &

(2) You have omitted a semi-colon at the end of one of your lines:

```
else {
    console.log("Error")
}
```

As for you problem --

The code:

```
numberOfCastles = document.getElementById("attackerCastlesNum");
numberOfForts = document.getElementById("attackerFortNum");
```

Will not return the values of the input element(s) -- it will instead returning an instance of the DOM object representative of the element.

You should instead use --

```
numberOfCastles = document.getElementById("attackerCastlesNum").value;
numberOfForts = document.getElementById("attackerFortNum").value;
```

Additionally you have constructions such as:

```
if (troopsCanCarry == silverRequired) { ... }
else if (troopsCanCarry > silverRequired) { ... }
else if (troopsCanCarry < silverRequired) { ... }
```

You should consider swapping the 3rd else-if condition with an else; the first two tests ensure that the third condition is met -- e.g.

```
if (troopsCanCarry == silverRequired) { ... }
else if (troopsCanCarry > silverRequired) { ... }
else { ... }
```